# SharePoint 2013 choice column DropDownlist

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, choice-field

Is it possible to update a Choice column with workflow ?

I have created a list and created a lookup column that displays the name 
**Company**.
I have connected the column to a document the Library of
and activated *Meta Navigation*.

I want to create a column that retrieves data from the lookup and places it in a Choice column, so that I can use it in *Meta navigation*!

Is there any easier way ?